# BackboneJS: is there a list of default events one can bind to?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I know we can create our own events in Backbone.js like

object.trigger('myEvent');

I also know there are some default events like the `change` or `change:<attributename>`

now i'm wondering, is there a list somewhere of these default events?
**i am looking for a specific event that triggers when someone navigates away from a view,
so either in the removing of the view, or perhaps when a route is changed,**
I just hope i don't have to hack in my own event and it can't hurt to see a full list of these events for further reference.

Comment: Have you considered looking through the source code? It's even annotated, it should not be hard to find what you're looking for. http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html

Comment: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/ - the menu on the left should work as a good TOC like view and you can (and should) have the annotated source code open too like @Tomalak suggested :)

Comment: The list of events is in the FAQ: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update** seems like the list did exist already, as benoit describes in the comment above,
it can be found here... http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-events

---

so it seems such a list does not exist, well, i took it upon me to go through the annotated source and present the list here for everyone who might ever need it.

i do also make this a community wiki post, so i hope it will be updated by any of you who feel the need to. whether a new Backbone version comes with extra events or i've got something wrong, feel free to edit.

here goes the list of events triggered by backbone itself:

- `change:<attributename>`

  fired after using `model.set({<attributename>, 'value'});` 
  to indicate the attribute was changed.
- `change`

  fired after using `model.set({<attributename>, 'value'});` 
  to indicate the model was changed. this fire's on any attribute you change.
- `destroy`

  fires after you destroy a model, `model.destroy({options});`
- `error`

  fires after a model is validated and 1 of the validations fails, 
  if however a specific error callback function is passed in, that one will 
  be executed instead of the `error` event.

  also fires when you do NOT give an error callback to the following model methods:

  ```
  model.fetch();
  model.save();
  model.destroy();
  ```
- `reset`

  fired when a collection is sorted through the `collection.sort({options});` method 
  also fired when specifically asking to reset a collection through `collection.reset(models, {options});`
- `add`

  fired when a model is added to a collection `collection.add(models, {options});`
- `remove`

  fired when a model is removed from a collection... `collection.remove(models, {options});`

Comment: answered my own question, though only because it was a direct answer to the question, the other person did gave good insight as to how to work around it but was not directly answering the question

Answer (score 1):

The particular event you are looking for does not exist, but it can be added easily.

```
Backbone.View.prototype.remove = function() {
  $(this.el).remove();
  this.trigger('remove', this);
  return this;
}
```

There is also a 'navigate' event built in, if you are using the Router.